# Is there a search engine to look up formulas in physics.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, soft-question

I was wondering if there is a site where it is possible to look up formulas. For math.stackexchange, it is possible to use https://www.searchonmath.com/ or https://approach0.xyz/search/. But those don't index physics.stackexchange.

Outside of Stack Exchange, there is also https://zbmath.org/formulae/, but I don’t know anything equivalent in physics for this one either.

Comment: Google works if you use it right, but you’d have to know the syntax of the equation beforehand

Comment: yes those sites are made to look using the syntax of the formula, you can google a syntax too but is not made for that purpose so you get less meaningful results

Comment: Thanks for migrating the question and editing my grammar